# How to sync time between windows and linux computers?

Tags: operating-system, windows-xp, ntp, rhel5

We have several linux and windows boxes and some of their clocks will drift. Is there a quick way to set up one of these systems as a time server and have the others point to them? This will need to work on a stand alone network. The OSs are specifically XP and RHEL5 for this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) Server on one of the Linux machines and have the others point to it.

- [How to setup a NTP-Server with Redhat](http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2007/08/setting-up-your-own-ntp-server.html)

Connect to the NTP-Server in Redhat:

- `ntpdate -du ntpservername`

Connect to the NTP-Server in Windows XP:

- Right click on the clock in the system tray
- Choose adjust time
- On the `internet time` tab insert your server hostname